# Partitive before adjective?

Tags: grammaire, articles, adjectifs, partitif

I'm having a hard time finding a definitive reference for a simple question: how do partitive articles behave before adjectives? Most resources mention that *des* becomes *de*, but it's unclear to me what happens in the singular, e.g. *Je veux du bon vin*, or *je veux de bon vin*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two cases in which the partitive article changes from the default “du”/“de la”/“de l'”/“des” to “de”/“d'”.

- With a *plural* noun, when there is an adjective before the noun. There is no such phenomenon in with a singular noun.

  > J'ai bu de bons vins.   (*I have drunk some good wines.*)
  >   J'ai bu des vins excellents.   (*I have drunk some excellent wines.*)
  >   J'ai bu du bon vin.   (*I have drunk some good wine.*)

  By the way, “des bons vins” is also grammatically correct, but it is the plural of the indefinite article: “un bon vin” → “des bons vins” (a good wine → good wines), “du bon vin” → “de bons vins” (some good wine → some good wines). In French, like in English, there are many contexts where either a plural indefinite article or a plural partitive article could work, and the similarity of the articles contributes to the fuzziness.
- When the noun phrase is a direct complement of a negated verb.

  > Je n'ai pas bu de bon vin.   (*I have not drunk any good wine.*)
  >   Je n'ai pas bu de bons vins.   (*I have not drunk any good wines.*)
  >   Je n'ai pas bu de vins excellents.   (*I have not drunk any excellent wines.*)

Comment: Thanks! I did find one reference that says the rule applies to the singular case as well. Any thoughts? https://books.google.com/books?id=K5AGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=partitif+before+adjectif&source=bl&ots=v8d8VdRz9O&sig=L-vsmHRZWbWHPozEGwonyalW3j8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxhcmct4zLAhUEJR4KHcovAuUQ6AEITjAH#v=onepage&q=partitif%20before%20adjectif&f=false

Comment: @AlanO'Donnell Hmmm, I think it was the case a few centuries ago, but in modern French, “voici de bon pain” is just wrong. I'm no expert in the history of French, but I think even by 1847 this would have been dated or regional.

Comment: In "when the noun phrase is a complement of a negated verb", complement = direct object ? I'm not even sure whether partitive articles occur in other types of complement.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Indeed, only for a direct object. Not for an indirect object, e.g. “je n'ai pas pensé à du bon vin”.