# Why is it 'les longues serviettes' but 'les pantalons longs'?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

I'm confused because 'long' is supposedly one of the adjectives coming before the noun, but for some reason, I've always learned 'long pants' as 'pantalons longs'... a quick search on many translators yields the same. Could someone explain this rule?

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apr%c3%a8s-un-nom-when-do-adjectives-go

Answer (score 1):

It is actually kinda weird but you can say it in both way for those 2 examples :

De **longs** pantalons = Des pantalons **longs**

Same goes for the "serviette" example :

Des serviettes **longues** = De **longues** serviettes

But you could also say :

"**Des** longues serviettes" instead of "**De** longues serviettes"

Wether you use in one way or another depends on how you want to formulate your sentence and on wich one sound the most natural.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm a bit confused about how you used 'des' and 'de' respectively, however. As 'des' is the indefinite plural article, it would make sense to say 'des longues serviettes' as in 'some long towels'. But 'de' means 'from' or 'of', so I'm not too sure how this construction works instead of 'des'. What am I missing? Thx

Comment: @Evan De doesn't only mean 'from' or 'of' saying "de longues serviettes" is some sort of more sustained way of saying "des longues serviettes" wich would be more coarse langage.

Comment: For the reason you use ***de** longs pantalons* but ***des** pantalons longs* in formal French grammar, see [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/partitive-before-adjective/17873#17873).