# Why is there not des rather than de "je pars bientôt pour de longues vacances."

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

I read that sometimes french prefer to use de for formal language rather than des.

Does that apply here?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/10869/1893 Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »

Comment: Because the partitive becomes *de* rather than *des* before a plural adjective + noun.  [See Lawless French](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/partitive-article/) and [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/partitive-before-adjective/17873#17873).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is what applies here. Assuming you saw this in a book, this is the most common way to phrase this in a non-casual register.

Also, in this case you'll often find the adjective before the noun, as in your example. It's uncommon to have one (*de* instead of *des*) and not the other (the ajdective before the noun).

Answer (score 2):

> Variation des for­mes de l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni ([Kalmbach](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html#045))
>
> Les for­mes de base de l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni sont **un / une / des / du / de la** (et la va­rian­te devant voyelle **de l’**). Dans cer­tains cas, on utilise une au­tre for­me :
>
> •   quand l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni dé­ter­mi­ne un **nom au pluriel pré­cé­dé d’un ad­jec­tif an­té­po­sé**, il prend ha­bi­tu­el­le­ment (dans le code écrit) la for­me **de** ;
> •  quand l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni dé­ter­mi­ne un grou­pe no­mi­nal qui est com­plé­ment direct d’un ver­be à la for­me né­ga­ti­ve, il prend sou­vent la for­me **de**, mais ce n’est pas sys­té­ma­ti­que ;
> •   après la pré­po­si­tion **de**, les for­mes d’ar­ti­cle com­mençant par un d (**des, du, de la, de**) ne sont pas exprimées, elles « s’effacent ». C’est la règle d’effacement.
>
> Ces chan­ge­ments très fré­quen­ts sont un des mécanismes fondamentaux de la gram­maire du fran­çais, qu’il faut bien com­pren­dre et savoir utiliser couramment.
>
> Règle générale
>
> Quand l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni pluriel (pas singulier, ni massif) **des** dé­ter­mi­ne un grou­pe no­mi­nal contenant un ad­jectif an­té­po­sé (qui précède le nom), il prend la for­me **de**.
> Com­pa­rer :
>
> **­ad­jec­tif postposé**;                                                                 **ad­jec­tif an­té­po­sé**
> Il m’a offert des fleurs magnifiques                                 Il m’a offert de très belles fleurs.
> Je vous donne un ex­em­ple différent.                            Je vous donne d’au­tres ex­em­ples.
> L’artiste a dessiné des figures gigantesques dans la neige.
>                                                                                        L’artiste a dessiné de gigantesques                                                                                       figures dans la neige.
>
> La règle s’applique aus­si quand l’ad­jec­tif est modifié par un ad­ver­be, qui vient se placer entre l’adjectif et le dé­ter­mi­nant :
>
> ■ Il a dit de si belles choses.
> ■ Ce sont de très bons ex­em­ples.
> ■ Elle a d’assez bons résultats scolaires.
>
> À noter :
>
> a) dans ce cas, le mot **de** est une des for­mes possibles de l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni, comme **un, du, des** etc. Ce n’est pas une pré­po­si­tion.
> b) la transforma­tion de l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni en **de** ne concerne que la for­me comp­ta­ble du pluriel de l’ar­ticle in­dé­fi­ni (des) !
> c) au singulier (**un, une**) et au massif (**du, de la**), il n’y a pas de transforma­tion de­vant ad­jec­tif an­té­po­sé :
> • une grande mai­son, du bon vin.
>
> Exceptions : mots com­po­sés
>
> Certains grou­pes ad­jec­tif an­té­po­sé + nom com­me *petit pois*, *grande per­son­ne* etc., for­ment des mots com­po­sés, c’est-à-dire une seule unité sé­man­ti­que. Dans ce cas-là, l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni pluriel qui les dé­ter­mine ne change pas de for­me, puis­que l’ad­jec­tif n’est plus un vrai ad­jec­tif qua­li­fi­ca­tif (dont la fonc­tion est de qualifier, de modifier le sens du nom) : le grou­pe ad­jec­tif + nom est lexicalisé, il est devenu un élé­ment au­to­nome du lexique :
>
> ■ un petit pois → des petits pois
> ■ un jeune homme  → des jeunes hommes
> ■ une jeune fille → des jeunes filles
> ■ une petite cuillère  → des petites cuillères
> ■ un petit four  → des petits fours
> ■ une grande per­son­ne  → des grandes per­son­nes
> Com­pa­rer éga­le­ment :
> ■ un grand ensemble   → de grands ensembles  [set]
> ■ un grand ensemble → des grands ensembles. [orchestra]

(*See  full text for more precisions*)

Careful speakers use "de";  this means that  you  can use  "de" all  the time (when  an adjective precedes  the  noun).

> ([Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-11349.php))
>
> DE + ADJECTIF EPITHETE + NOM
>
> Même si au pluriel, l'article indéfini est **des**, si un adjectif épithète est placé devant le nom dans la langue écrite ou dans la langue orale soignée, on le remplace par **de** : (même s'il arrive qu'à l'oral usuel vous entendiez parfois que "des" est employé).
> • Dans ce quartier, il y a de grands restaurants.