# Question about avoir de/ faire de + plural

Tags: articles

I am self-studying French using the Contacts book by Valette.

I came across the following expressions: **avoir de bons amis** and **faire de grands progrès**. I am confused why the book uses "de" in both cases since the noun that follows is plural.

Shouldn't it be *avoir des bons amis* (with *des* being the plural of un/une) and *faire des grands progrès* (with *des* being the partitive article)?

I would appreciate some clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partitive before adjective?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/partitive-before-adjective)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these two examples **bons amis** and **grand progrès** are treated as [mass nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)

des bons amis = multiple, specific, good friends, possible to list.

de bons amis = multiple good friends, in general.