# De quelque chose apparaître ou quelque chose apparaitre?

Tags: prépositions

According to the dictionary of the French Academy the verb apparaître does not require a preposition, like in the example:

> *Les difficultés apparaissent déjà.*

Yet, in both online and  printed sources I have come across sentences like these:

> *De nouvelles possibilities apparaissent.
>
> De délicats souliers en verre apparaissent à ses pieds menus, elle ressemble à une princesse.*

Is it acceptable to use apparaître with a prepositional phrase with DE? Does the verb acquire a new meaning in this case?

Many thanks for providing an answer.

Comment: The *de* here is not a preposition but the partitive article; *some* delicate glass shoes appear on her small feet. (Not that you would ever use *some* here in English, but you need it in French.)

Comment: Shouldn't there be DES before a plural noun?

Comment: In formal writing, if there is a plural adjective before the noun, the partitive article is simply *de*. See the answer to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/partitive-before-adjective). 
 (Apparently, this rule is often ignored in speech.)

Comment: Thanks for such a clear explanation, Peter.

Comment: _De/des_ is tricky. I would say: _de nouvelles possibilités apparaissent_, but most probably _des possibilités nouvelles sont apparues_, for example.

Comment: Does the usage of DE/DES depend on the position of the adjective modifying the noun, Frank?

Comment: @Val Yes, indeed. See the link in the response by Peter.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I'm afraid I overlooked the link. I appreciate your comment!

Answer (score 3):

The *de* here is not a preposition but the partitive article<sup>1</sup>:

> *some* delicate glass shoes appear on her small feet.

Not that you would ever use *some* here in English, but you need it in French.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>In formal writing, if there is a plural adjective before the noun, the partitive article is simply *de*. See [Partitive before adjective?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/partitive-before-adjective)</sub>