# difference between "du bon vin" and "de bon vin"

Tags: grammaire, articles, de

This question has bothered me for a while.
When I learned french long time ago, our teacher said: "l'article partitif means some".
Example: J'ai mangé du fromage -> I ate some cheese,
j'ai bu de la bière -> I drank some beer.

Later, we have learned that when put l'article partitif in front of an adjective, it often maintain "de".
Example: J'ai de bons amis -> I have some good friends. In this case, we don't say "j'ai des bons amis".

But here comes the problem, in one exercise there are 2 sentences: "j'ai bu du bon vin" and "J'ai bu de bons vins", and they both are right. I am confused, what is the difference between these 2 sentences and why we put "du" in front of "bon"?

thanks

Comment: sorry for not being clear. My question is rather what is the difference between bois du bon vin et bois de bons vins, or can we say "bois des bons vins"? are they different?

Comment: I believe you can do the same in English: _I drank some good wine_ and _I drank some good wines_ (with an "s").

Comment: You generally use *de* before a plural adjective, and *du / de la* before a singular adjective. But there are exceptions; it's complicated. [See this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/partitive-before-adjective/17873#17873).